Timers, Tasks and Threads?
I have an application that consumes four inputs (web cam). For each of these inputs I'm trying to call an API every 200ms. The API doesn't return within 200ms - and in reality, I only need to ensure that every call runs to completion. I don't mind if it's not instantaneous, or even close to it. So I imagine every 200ms, those calls need to be queued if previous calls haven't completed..?
At the moment I have one timer, set to fire every 200ms, which looks like this:
private async void OnTimerTickFront(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() => Method1Async());
    Task t2 = Task.Run(() => Method2Async());
    Task t3 = Task.Run(() => Method3Async());
    Task t4 = Task.Run(() => Method4Async());
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
}

Now, because each of these methods may take longer than 200ms to complete - I'm wondering if WhenAll is the best way of ensuring that each timer tick actually completes its task.
I've tried a few approaches (mainly old school threadpool and threading stuff), but I'm aware my knowledge is lacking here and would really appreciate some advice.
It's debugger to debugger.
Thanks,
Mike

It's not entirely clear what exactly you want to ensure. That the next tick does not begin processing until the previous one has finished? Then it's already not happening, async void cannot be awaited, so as far as the timer is concerned, you have completed handling the tick event as soon as you begin calling Task.WhenAll.

That's a good point. So for each of the four webcam feeds, I'm grabbing a frame every 200ms and firing that out to an API. I then process the API results. I don't want to miss any of the 200ms interval frames. So I just want to queue those requests.

WhenAll doesn't ensure that the tasks complete. It only lets you pause execution until they have. It might pause forever.

All this sounds to me as if you might want to turn this 90°. Do all 4 images need to be taken at approximately the same time? If not they don't need to wait for each other and especially do neither of them need to await the end of the processing pipeline. Right?

Fildor, that's actually a good shout - I could try and stagger them. Thanks

You have async void method, which unfortunately won't propagate any exceptions during async method calls.
But what you can do is to store in some private variable (or collection) the task of WaitAll and apply producer consumer pattern for awaiting them, something like this:
private async Task ConsumeWithWhileAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var task = await _reader.ReadAsync();
        try
        {
            // You can handle here results of tasks, if you have some return value.
            await task;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("caught");
        }
    }
}

public async void OnTimerTickFront(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() => Method1Async());
    Task t2 = Task.Run(() => Method2Async());
    Task t3 = Task.Run(() => Method3Async());
    Task t4 = Task.Run(() => Method4Async());

    _ = _writer.WriteAsync(Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4));
}

For that you need to have following fields:
private readonly ChannelWriter<Task> _writer;
private readonly ChannelReader<Task> _reader;

which are initialized by:
var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Task>();
_writer = channel.Writer;
_reader = channel.Reader;

You also could implement handler for TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException Event
Last note If yourMethod1Async are truly async, you can simplify your code to:
Task t1 = Method1Async();
Task t2 = Method2Async();
Task t3 = Method3Async();
Task t4 = Method4Async();

Also you would need to create some disposal method, maybe implement IDisposable interface, to stop consuming loop and optionally await the tasks.

I will report back. I really appreciate the help
